# Problem when converting factors to numeric

Tags: r, types

`column1` is large column in a dataset
Suppose that `column1` in a datasethas values: 1,2,3,4 (datatype factor)-
Then I define

```
column2 <- as.numeric(column1)
```

column2 is showing values: 2,3,4,5 #(+1 the column1 values)

---

column3 <- as.numeric(as.character(column1)) #now column3 is showing correct values i.e. 1,2,3,4

Comment: Check `levels(column1)`. The first level will be something other than 1. `as.numeric` returns the positions in the levels.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that factors cannot be transformed to numerics directly.
Check this example:

```
x <- factor(0:3)
x
[1] 0 1 2 3
Levels: 0 1 2 3
as.numeric(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4
as.character(x)
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3"
```

In order to properly convert `x` to numeric you can do either this:

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

or any other possibility suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information).

In general when creating data.frames I would suggest working with factors by setting `stringsAsFactors = F`.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer.